# device and drivers connections

Tags: linux-kernel, serial-port, linux-device-driver, uart, tty

There is a device that is connected to the controller uart port (in Linux 2.6), and which generates an interrupt on gpio. I wrote the driver of the Space user to communicate with the device, but I want to move this driver into the kernel. Does anyone have a similar experience?

There is a driver of uart port from freescale do not really understand how this driver connects to the device through function probe (). Not yet found where the structure of the device is created and at what point and at what time is called probe (). Perhaps the connection occurs during file creation /dev/ttymxc0 ..1 ..2 ..3 (associations on the port) via udev (also not yet know how udev works)?

Another question, if I'll write a driver of the external uart device, then would not it be a conflict when two drivers are connected to the same device? Or the driver who was the first one and managed?

Comment: i found platform device structure in kernel-mx53shm/arch/arm/mach-mx5/serial.c with init and platform_device_register(&mxc_uart_device3);

driver init with probe: kernel/drivers/serial/mxc_uart.c
and i want to connect device to my driver, and i don't know how to do it.

Comment: in the probe function there is uart_add_one_port(&mxc_reg, &mxc_ports[id]->port);
is adding uart port to tty driver (may be there is a way to add uart port to my driver?)

Comment: any answers please, and any mind, will be glad)

Comment: may a my driver connect to existence uart driver (mxcintuart)? how to do this?

Comment: If I understand this correctly, your Linux host has a remote device that has a serial connection.  You want to move this device handler from user space to kernel space.  This sounds like the SPI framework: there's the "SPI Master Controller" driver for the host-side controller (or your host's UART port) and a "SPI Protocol" driver for each SPI slave device (or your remote device).  Problem is that there is no such framework AFAIK for UART connections.  The typical driver for a UART is written as an interface for a TTY.  Kernel drivers are only for local devices, not "remote" devices.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, very good idea! It may would be justified by my superior. Im new to linux engeneering (i was electronics and microcontrollers) in my new work. But I will think may be not standart way for this decision? Some similar question I found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9420798/link-between-low-level-drivers-and-tty-drivers/29891239#29891239

Comment: May be it is need to write a line discipline with own protocol to communicate with external board? And then there is another question: how to connect line discipline to existence tty driver from kernel module?

Comment: Whether a line discipline will meet your requirements is something only can determine.  A tty line discipline driver is not as flexible or capable as the SPI protocol driver, but that is all you have within the tty framework. See [Writing a Kernel Line Discipline](http://www.linux-mag.com/id/1891/)

Comment: So I think that it is shortage in kernel. My first driver in kernel will be live in user space. Now I'll think about better synchronization between my module and user space program (blocking on read.. i.e. waiting for interrupt).

Comment: what is the serio.h interface in kernel? I saw a uart driver thrue the serio interface (touch screen controller), but don't understand how it works. May be answer for my question is hidden on serio? Who knows?

Comment: Serio devices are typically input devices such as mice and keyboards, and not communication ports such as a UART.  See slide 2 of http://rts.lab.asu.edu/web_438/CSE438_598_slides_yhlee/438_8_Linux_input_system.pdf  Also see http://www.embeddedlinux.org.cn/EssentialLinuxDeviceDrivers/final/ch07lev1sec2.html

Comment: Serio also has RS232 interface (from header file serio.h). Mice and keyboard also has communication protocol. My external device is a keyboard with ATmega ucontroller. I saw that serio has 3 interface: connect(); disconnect(); interrupt(); And don't know how to use interrupt interface in serio, and how to use serio itself)

Comment: *"My external device is a keyboard..."* -- After almost two weeks, you finally decide to mention this detail?  You start with a vague questions about UART and expect useful answers?

Comment: Sensor keyboard with our own protocol. But instead the keyboard may be any other rs232 device with some non standart protocol. Input event for keyboard is not difficult task, because there much information in internet. Now i write a line discipline for keyboard, so it will need to open port and set line discipline from user space. Another way I do not see now.

Comment: Writed line discipline, its works. But now I open tty port from C code. How to open and attach line discipline from BusyBox shell?
No ldattach. `getty line /dev/ttymxc3 speed 115200 linedisc N_MOUSE ` do not work (bad speed)

Comment: my external device (thrue com port) needs to operate in sleep mode, but line discipline has no suspend / resume callbacks.
how it to realize?